# Twitter API hide the URL at the end of the text

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API to retrieve data from a collection the problem is the returned `text` or `full_text` string has a short URL appended at the end of the tweet.

Example:
`Together we can do more than any one of us alone. t.co/cf1lVHw0i8`

I have the following that replaces and converts links and hashtags.

```
    function linkify_tweet($tweet) {
    
      //Convert urls to <a> links
      $tweet = preg_replace("/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $tweet);
    
      //Convert hashtags to twitter searches in <a> links
      $tweet = preg_replace("/#([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a target=\"_new\" href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=$1\">#$1</a>", $tweet);
    
      //Convert attags to twitter profiles in <a> links
      $tweet = preg_replace("/@([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>", $tweet);
    
      //Remove links
      $pattern = "/[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+/i";
      $replacement = "";
      $tweet=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $tweet);

      return $tweet;
    
    }
```

The last regular expression removes all the links but I want only to remove the shorten URL at the end and keep if any other links exist in the `text`.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Append a `$` to the pattern that matches the url.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Twitter's shortened links always follow the format provided in your example, you can simply use this

**Solution**

`t\.co\/\S+\s*$`

Note you'll need to perform two matches, first figure out if it found a non `t.co` link exists. If it did, then remove the `t.co` link with the above pattern.